# convert object to json with name properties

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm looking to create a JSON string from a DTO with `name` and `values` for each property with `Json` or/and `Jackson` annotation
.
**My DTO :**

```
class DTO {
     @??? = "individual.lastName"
     private List<String> lastName = ["LastName1","LastName2"];
     @??? = "individual.firstName" 
     private List<String> firstName = ["FistName1"];
     ...
}
```

**result expected :**

```
{
"fields": [
    {
        "name": "individual.lastName",
        "values": [
            "LastName1",
            "LastName2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "individual.firstName",
        "values": [
            "FirstName1"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement(name = "individual.lastName")`?

Comment: @JsonProperty("name") but not map with real name (individual.lastname) or @JsonSerialize not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for creating a separate json object with two properties for each of the DTO's properties. In other words, you want to convert the `List`s `Map`s and serialize the `Map`s.

This could be achieved with a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.Converter` class + `@JsonSerialize` annotation.  The problem is that Jackson associates a converter to a Type, so all `List` typed properties will have the same converter. Another problem is that the converter does not know the name of the DTO property. it is expected to process the value only.

So we are left with a custom serializer for the DTO class that is tailored to the specific POJO, has access to all the properties and can explicitly produce whatever is required.  I added a custom annotation that allows specifying "json name" for each dto property:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD) //can use in field only.
public @interface JsonName
{   
    String value();
}


@JsonSerialize(using = DTOSerializer.class)
public class DTO
{
    @JsonName("individual.lastName")
    public List<String> lastName = Arrays.asList("LastName1", "LastName2");
    @JsonName("individual.firstName")
    public List<String> firstName = Arrays.asList("firstName1");
}
```

The custom serializer fetches all the fields of the dto, looks for the @JsonName annotation and assigns the json "name" property from the annotation's value:

```
public class DTOSerializer extends JsonSerializer<DTO>
{
    @Override
    public void serialize(DTO value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeFieldName("fields");
        gen.writeStartArray();
        Field[] fields = dto.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(JsonName.class)) {
                Object fieldValue = null;
                try {
                    fieldValue = field.get(dto);
                } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (fieldValue != null) {
                    String fieldName = ((JsonName)field.getAnnotation(JsonName.class)).value();
                    gen.writeStartObject();
                    gen.writeStringField("name", fieldName);
                    gen.writeObjectField("values", fieldValue);
                    gen.writeEndObject();
                }
            }
        }

        gen.writeEndArray();
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Calling

```
new ObjectMapper().writeValue(System.out, new DTO());
```

produces exactly as expected

```
{"fields":[{"name":"individual.lastName","values":["LastName1","LastName2"]},{"name":"individual.firstName","values":["firstName1"]}]}
```

Comment: I want for exemple:  
public Class DTO {
  @JSonName("name")
  @JsonName("lastname")
   => {"name";"individidual.lastName", ....
  @JsonValueName(values)
  @JsonValue(var firsname value)
  => ... "values": ["....","...."] }
  public List<String> firstName


I have 60 properties to map....

Comment: using the custom serializer, you have total freedom to generate the json you require, so you need to develop the metadata that is required to generate the properties. you can either populate hashmap with property names, values or you can write your own annotations that you can investigate in the serializer

Comment: I added a custom annotation that allows specifying "json name" for each dto property, see edited answer

Comment: Thank you a lot. That's what I wanted excatement